# Show that $f$ is monomorphism and prove that for : $\left\langle v,w \right\rangle _{X}=\left\langle f(v),f(w) \right\rangle _{Y}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $(X,\left\langle \cdot , \cdot \right\rangle _{X})$, $(Y,\left\langle \cdot , \cdot \right\rangle _{Y})$ are euclidean spaces. Linear map $f \in L(X,Y)$ is such that for all $v \in X$: $\left\langle v,v \right\rangle _{X}=\left\langle f(v),f(v) \right\rangle _{Y}$. 
>  (a) Show that $f$ is monomorphism. 
>  (b) Prove that for all $v,w \in X$: $\left\langle v,w \right\rangle _{X}=\left\langle f(v),f(w) \right\rangle _{Y}$

I know that $f$ is monomorphism when $ker f=\left\{ 0\right\} $, $f$ is injective and performs each linearly independent system on a linearly independent system. However I think this information are insufficient in this task and I don't know how can I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=0$ implies that $0=\langle f(x),f(x)\rangle_Y=\langle x,x\rangle_X$ we deduce that $x=0$ since $\langle,.,\rangle_X$ is a scalar product.

$\langle f(u+v),f(u+v)\rangle_Y=\langle f(u),f(u)\rangle_Y+2\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle+\langle f(v),f(v)\rangle_Y=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle_X=\langle u,u\rangle_X+2\langle u,v\rangle_X+\langle v,v\rangle_X$ implies

that $\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle_Y=\langle u,v\rangle_X$ since $\langle f(u),f(u)\rangle=\langle u,u\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

a)Suppose f is not a monomorphism. Then there exists v, w such that v $\not=$ w and f(v) = f(w). Since f is linear, that implies f(v)-f(w) = f(v-w) = 0. Then

$$0\not= <v-w,v-w>_X = <f(v-w),f(v-w)>_Y = 0,$$a contradiction.

b) We use a similar technique to prove b)

$$<v-w,v-w>_X = <v,v>_X - 2<v,w>_X + <w,w>_X$$

$<f(v-w),f(v-w)>_Y$ = 
$$<f(v)-f(w),f(v)-f(w)>_Y = <f(v),f(v)>_Y-2<f(v),f(w)>_Y + <f(w),f(w)>_Y.$$

Combining the two, we get 
$$-2<v,w>_X = -2<f(v),f(w)>Y \checkmark$$